# Different TapGestureRecognizer for each row

Tags: xaml, xamarin, events, touch, gesture

```
<ContentView>
    <Grid InputTransparent="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="Algebra"/>
            <Label Text="number 1" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Switch IsToggled="True"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
                Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
                />

        <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="Arithmetics" />
            <Label Text="number 2" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Switch IsToggled="True"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Grid.Column="1"
                />
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

I have two rows with each having 2 labels and a switch. How can I invoke two different Tap events, for each row. Something like this:

```
<ROW1?.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped1" />
        </ROW?.GestureRecognizers>


<ROW2?.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped2" />
        </ROW?.GestureRecognizers>
```

I'm new, but it seems Switch toggle doesn't work while in grid, which is strange.

UI image:
[image: UI]

Comment: I would focus on why the Switch isn't working.  AFAIK you can't apply a gesture to an entire grid row

Comment: If someone can show me how to do it with two SwitchCells in XAML i would be very happy. I was trying with SwitchCells at beggining, but failed. Now I'm thinking to try that again, because basically thats what my UI requires.

Comment: Cell types are only used in ListViews and Tables.  You should be able to use the normal Switch control in a Grid.

Comment: ok, thank you for putting me on path. Switch does work now :)

Comment: If question is answered and issue is resolved, please add an answer with the solution and accept it. (You can accept your own answers). Doing this would keep potentially helpful people from looking at this question thinking it still needs an answer and save these helpful folks some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't simply apply a gesture to an entire grid row,

I decided to just use Switch built-in functionality for my UI.

And all I did was add two different methods for each Switch:

```
<Grid InputTransparent="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Spacing="0"
             Grid.Row="0"
             VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Algebra"/>
        <Label Text="number 1" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Switch IsToggled="True"
            Toggled="method2"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
            Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
            />

    <StackLayout Spacing="0"
             Grid.Row="1"
             VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Arithmetics" />
        <Label Text="number 2" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Switch IsToggled="True"
        Toggled="method2"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        Grid.Column="1"
            />
</Grid>
```